# Specifying float size for 00.0

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqldatatypes

Considering I know the range of a field (0 - 10) and I only need to keep precision to one decimal place 00.0, what is the best field type for this column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data type you want is [`DECIMAL(3, 1)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html). Per the documentation, this will store any value from `-99.9` to `99.9`.

Comment: +1 i may have answered first but you gave them the proper example first

Comment: @JohnConde Good call adding it to your question, though. I know when I search for answers it's always nice to have all the information in one place.

Answer (score 6):

[DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html). A lot of people use `FLOAT` but that is unecessary in most situations.

```
DECIMAL(3,1)
```

Comment: +1 Ah blast, beat me to it. I need to learn to refresh the page.

Comment: Doesn't that give 0.00 not 00.0?

Comment: @amiawizard You're correct. I updated my answer and John's as well (although my edit to his question won't appear immediately).

Comment: It's funny that I can't edit my own answer because I've used up my votes for the day!

Comment: @JohnConde Is that how it works? I used up all of my question/answer votes for the day, but perhaps because I'm not actually *editing* the question (merely putting an edit in the approval queue) it still works for me.

Comment: I think votes for edits and questions/answers are separate. I reviewed 50 edits earlier which is what I think did me in. I didn't think it affected my own answers, though.